# GeoServer 503 service Problem accessing /geoserver/

Tags: geoserver

I recently installed GeoServer on Mac mini M1 2021, I installed following things

1. Java JRE 8
2. JAVA JDK 8
3. GeoServer 2.17 (binary)
4. I followed all steps according to https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/osx_binary.html
5. My echo $JAVA_HOME gives -> /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home

When I run sh startup.sh it's giving following error:

> HTTP ERROR 503
> Problem accessing /geoserver/. Reason:
> Service Unavailable

Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.18.v20190429

And logs says:
 
/geoserver/
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:698)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:804)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

What might be the problem?

Comment: Possibly an incompatibility between Geoserver and java versions? Try installing the Java 11 environment. Also note that that link you posted, is Geoserver 2.19

Comment: I tried installing Java 11 = > java version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.12+8-LTS-237)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.12+8-LTS-237, mixed mode)

Comment: java 11 will also require a newer version of Jetty as well. It may be that version of Jetty is the problem, so maybe try newer Jetty.

Comment: but jetty will be shipped with geoserver right?

Comment: GeoServer is tested for java 8 and java 11. The binary zip file contains also a compatible Jetty version. But the JAVA_HOME path looks odd.

Comment: What should be the ideal JAVA_HOME path for mac?

Comment: JAVA_HOME should be the path where your java is. Have you really installed it under "Internet Plug-ins"? Typical path seems to be /System/Library/Java...  https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/. You can also edit manually the startup.sh file and write correct JAVA_HOME into it is the system variable is wrong. BTW GeoServer does not need JDK.

Comment: I changed $JAVA_HOME path to - /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.12.jdk/Contents/Home
but still no luck

Comment: as an example, my java home is 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80   (windows). I don't tihnk you would have to point it to such a lower path - ie: remove contents/home from the path

Comment: startup sh says that it will take the JAVA_HOME path and add /bin/java to get the executable file.. that is why such path is set